# Running multiple Asyntask simultaneously

Tags: java, android

I have server client communication program at server side I have camera and that camera I am controlling by my android application as client it is working but the problem is when the server memory is full then server is stopping the camera and sending a message to client and and if client want to stop camera by it self then client is sending command to server and server stop the camera .
The problem is there only I am not getting the massage if I am getting the massage of "memory full" then I am not getting the massage "stopping camera "when user want to kill by itself and if am manage to get the "stopping camera " message then I am not getting the "memory full massage "

here is my code please help me 
thanks in advance

```
/** here is the recording start button I am calling a asyntask for recording
       * Record  and store video at battery control unit(server end) at background
       */
        record=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.record);
        record.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(socket==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connection not establised", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    pDialog.show();
                    suspended=false;
                    start=false;
                    new CommunicationTaskrec().execute();
                }
            }
        });
```

/** 
       * Async task for the record, which runs on back ground. 
       */

```
     public class CommunicationTaskrec  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String str = "3";
                PrintWriter out = null;
                try {
                      out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                            true);
                }   catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.println(str);
             String resultrec="testing the UI Thread update";
             BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }   catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                resultrec = in.readLine();
            }   catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Log.d("inside bg thread", resultrec);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, resultrec).sendToTarget();
            out.flush();
           // new Thread(new RecThread()).start();
           // new CommunicationTaskmemorycheck().execute();
            return resultrec; 
     }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
   }
```

//here is the message handler case

```
           /** 
            * Creating a dialog box which shows a timer for the recording time
            */
                 case MESSAGE_READ:
                final String readBuf = (String) msg.obj;
                String string1 ="no enough space left on device";

                if(readBuf !=null){

                    if(readBuf.equalsIgnoreCase(string1))
                    {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO Enough Space Left for Recording Please Remove some files at server end.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, readBuf, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //here is the dialog box where I have a stop button also by which user stopping the ///camera manually

                    View viewlist=MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.timer, null);
                    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                    dialog.setContentView(viewlist);
                    dialog.setTitle("Status.....");
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.valuerec);
                    text.setText("Want to stop the Recording ?");
                    TextView cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.curvaluerec);
                    cur_val.setText("Recording Duration..");
                    Button stop = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.start);
                    mChronometer = (Chronometer) dialog.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
                    mChronometer.start();
                    dialog.show();

                    //here a asyntask and it is used for getting the memory full message
                    //it run contentiously on background and when the memory is full it //recieve "memory full massage"

                       task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                         String result=null;
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            Runnable action = new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READcreate, result).sendToTarget();
                                }
                            };
                            try {

                                do {
                                    //Pause work if control is paused.
                                    //tControl.waitIfPaused();
                                    //Stop work if control is cancelled.
                                    if (tControl.isCancelled()) {
                                        suspended=true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    while(!suspended){
                                    String string1 ="memory full";
                                    BufferedReader in = null;
                                    try {
                                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        result = in.readLine();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 

                                    if((result!=null && result.equalsIgnoreCase(string1)) )
                                    {
                                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READcreate, result).sendToTarget();
                                        result=null;
                                        suspended=true;
                                        start=true;
                                        runOnUiThread(action);
                                        break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }while (!suspended);
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                    };
                    task.execute();
```

//here is the dialog box stop button where I have a runnable thread which is used for send //command to server when user want to stop recording manually

```
                        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            task.cancel(true);
                            tControl.cancel();
                            suspended=true;

                            dialog.dismiss();

                            dialog=null;
                            mChronometer.stop();

                            pDialog.show();

                            //this is the runnable thread where I am getting "stopping //camera "massage

                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
                                public void run() {
                                     while (true) {
                                        String str = "8";
                                        PrintWriter out = null;
                                        try {
                                              out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                    true);
                                        }   catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                     out.println(str);
                                     String resultcap=null;
                                     BufferedReader in = null;
                                    try {
                                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                                    }   catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        resultcap = in.readLine();
                                    }   catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READstoprunning, resultcap).sendToTarget();
                                        out.flush();
                                        //suspended=false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ).start();
                        }
                    });
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error server not respondingrec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 3):

change   execute() to  executeOnExecutor(AsynTask.ThreadpoolExecutor)

Comment: Sir it is working but at the very first time it is not working I mean if I open the application and put recording and after that I am manually stop the camera then I am not getting the stopping camera message but when I came back and again put recording and again put the  stop button then I  am getting the stopping camera massage .....actually it is sending to stop command to server and server is stopping the camera but I am not getting the message of server at the first time ...

Comment: Are you getting camera stopping event for all time?

Comment: no but when I put the stop button of dialog box it send the command to server and server stop the camera but the first time I am not getting this message

Answer (score 1):

[`AsyncTasks` doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke 
`executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])`

with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.